# How is better to create new elements with?

Tags: jquery

1. `jQuery('body').append('<div id="my-div" style="background: #fff">my text</div>');`
2. `jQuery('<div/>').attr('id', 'my-div').css('background', '#fff').html('my text');`
3. `jQuery('<div/>', {id: 'my-div', html: 'my text', css: {background: '#fff'}});`

So what is the best way? May be you have something else?

Comment: @Boaz This really doesn't look like a duplicate of the question you link to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third solution is the most concise, the easiest to read and to extend, and is generally considered the cleanest although the second one, which doesn't have to iterate over properties, might be a little faster.

The first one is slower as it asks for the browser to parse HTML (and also because it's the only one adding the element to the DOM, as noticed by Jan).

Here's the performance test : http://jsperf.com/add-element

But you may do as you like, in truth. Even the speed difference rarely matters here.

Comment: with third appears problems in explorer...

Comment: What problems ? In what version of explorer ?

Comment: for example if i use `class` without quotes IE 8 fails.

Comment: The first test could be much slower because it actually _appends_ something to the document. The latter two only _create_ elements.

Comment: Try now: http://jsperf.com/add-element/2

Comment: Now the speed difference is not so awesome, and there is no longer a difference between #2 and #3 for some reason.

Comment: @JanDvorak Well seen but the results are about the same : the second one still is slightly faster. But I wouldn't be concerned by this speed difference in a real application and I'm not sure the order wouldn't change in the future.

Comment: so, what method is the fastest? In my case on os x 10.8.2 with the latest safari and ff and also on virtual box in xp with IE 8 the best was second method.

Comment: @user1692333 #2 seems consistently the fastest. Stick to the most readable, though.

Comment: @user1692333 Just now, the second one is a little faster. But really that's not an important difference and maybe the next release of jQuery will have a different speed behavior.

Comment: @dystroy or maybe some browser loves parsing HTML but acts on DOM nodes as second-level citizens, turning DOM mutations to HTML mutations before performing them (IE is not that browser, though)

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
jQuery('<div/>').attr({'id': 'my-div',
                       'class': 'my-class'})
                .css({'background': '#fff',
                      'color':'#000'})
                .html('my text');
```

Answer (score 0):

i think nr.3

1.) if you want to change or access the div, you have to call a selector after the append!

2.) much of method calls, but all over the jquery definitions

3.) the fastest method, with one meethod call

you forgot to call `jQuery('body').append(yourGeneratedDiv);` after the 2.) and 3.) solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is my opinion. If wrong someone please correct me. For example if I am getting the complete HTML string I use the first one, because it will be faster. For example if I am getting the element configuration from different sources, for example you could say like model in MVC, from which you are actually constructing the element then 2nd 3rd methods are handy. 2nd and 3rd methods are almost same. In 2nd method you are just using chaining, but it will make things more dirtier. This is very slower than just appending the HTML as in first method. 3rd methods will just iterate through all properties of passed object and construct the same. But if you want to do the same using cleaner JavaScript, here is the code

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "Your HTML Content";
div.id = "someID";
div.cssText = "Your CSS Code" // or you can use below way
var divStyle = div.style;
divStyle['background-color'] = "#CCC" // Like this
document.getElementById('parentDIV').appendChild(div);
```

[Here](http://jsperf.com/native-appendchild-vs-jquery-append/4) is the speed comparison between jquery way and native way
But again,

If you are adding many widgets on fly, my suggestion is create HTML content based on configuration and use `innerHTML` it is very faster than appendChild every time. I have tested and observed this.

My suggestion would be please avoid jQuery whenever it is actually not needed, I agree that is powerful DOM library ever, but applying where actually it is not needed then your performance will be decreased.

Comment: Concerning your paragraph #4: `documentFragment`s are even faster.

Comment: Concerning #5: don't you consider developer time more precious than a few milliseconds shaved off by not using jQuery?

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I have just shown one way of doing the same considering the performance. But thanks for pointing it. I liked it.

Comment: `In 2nd method you are just using chaining, but it will make things more dirtier. This is very slower than just appending the HTML as in first method` -- I completely disagree (unless HTML is your starting point). Chaining is not slow - and with a bit of luck, debuggers will support that soon as well.

Comment: Yes, Developers time is very important. But the problem is when developing a very large application in that I need to add many elements on fly, using jQuery to append will make me screwed up. But when it is required we have use jQuery. Because it does job really better than any other library. I feel in small cases where jQuery really not needed will actually make us depend on jQuery all the time even in performance critical application. Here we develop very large scalable application but still we use jQuery for handling cross-browser things when required. That is my point.

Comment: @JanDvorak I can point out an example... If you see YUI, there to check an array YUI.UTILS.someOther.someOther.inArray you can use, but still they say use typeof or toString whenever required. Because it saves some time and very much faster than the actual thing. I agree with you that chaining is very faster but I completely disagree sometimes because it is not always faster

Comment: I agree - when adding lots of elements at once, performance may be a real concern, at which point you should grab DocumentFragments, or just create a DocumentFragment, append a lot of nodes there with jQuery (if that works), and append the DocumentFragment to the document.